# How to automatically go to file when there is only one match in xref?

Tags: xref

I don't see the point in displaying xref with one match. Hope there is a simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `xref-show-definitions-buffer`
>
> Show the definitions list in a regular window.
>
> When only one definition found, jump to it right away instead.

You can also keep using `xref-show-definitions-buffer` (to keep seeing the Xref buffer when there are multiple matches), just extend it to the "other" case as well:

```
(setq xref-show-xrefs-function #'xref-show-definitions-buffer)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are suggesting: are you suggesting that the OP rewrite the function `xref-show-definitions-buffer` along the lines suggested in the other answer?

Comment: No, just use the above one-liner. `xref-show-definitions-buffer` already does "go to file when there is only one match". It is its main distinction.

Comment: OK - you might want to clarify the answer (I found it a bit mystifying), but that's interesting: I'll have to try it out at some point.

Comment: I hope the above is easier to understand, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xref-show-definitions-completing-read`:

```lisp
(setq xref-show-definitions-function #'xref-show-definitions-completing-read
      xref-show-xrefs-function       #'xref-show-definitions-completing-read)
```

*Update*: If you want to keep using the xref buffer when there are multiple matches, you can write your own function, based on, but slightly modified from, `xref--show-xref-buffer` and `xref-show-definitions-completing-read`:

```lisp
(defun my-xref--show-xref-buffer (fetcher alist)
  (cl-assert (functionp fetcher))
  (let* ((xrefs
          (or
           (assoc-default 'fetched-xrefs alist)
           (funcall fetcher)))
         (xref-alist (xref--analyze xrefs))
         (dd default-directory)
         buf)
    (if (not (cdr xrefs))
        (xref-pop-to-location (car xrefs) (assoc-default 'display-action alist))
      (progn
        (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create xref-buffer-name)
          (setq default-directory dd)
          (xref--xref-buffer-mode)
          (xref--show-common-initialize xref-alist fetcher alist)
          (pop-to-buffer (current-buffer))
          (setq buf (current-buffer)))
        (xref--auto-jump-first buf (assoc-default 'auto-jump alist))
        buf))))

(setq xref-show-xrefs-function 'my-xref--show-xref-buffer)
```

I just added a check copied from `xref-show-definitions-completing-read`:

```lisp
(if (not (cdr xrefs))
    (xref-pop-to-location (car xrefs) (assoc-default 'display-action alist))
  (progn
    ;; original logic
    ))
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to keep xref interface when there is multiple matches

Comment: @albert200000 Updated